# How to iterate and compare through a list of string inside if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, xml-parsing

I am parsing an XML and fetching the selected tag values from the XML and storing it in the List.
As I then want to show these values in the gridview. But how do I compare these values for multiple values inside the "IF" condition loop.

```
protected List<QueueListItems> GetQueueDetails(string xmlfile)
{
    var listofitems = new List<QueueListItems>();

    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load(xmlfile);
    // XmlNodeList itemnodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("//PublisherProperty/Name");
    XmlNodeList itemnodes = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("PublisherProperty");
    foreach (XmlElement node in itemnodes)
    {
        if (node.FirstChild.InnerText = "Channel" || "QueueManager" || "QueueServer" || "QueueName")
            {
                listofitems.Add(new QueueListItems()
                {
                    Text = node.FirstChild.InnerText,
                    Value = node.FirstChild.NextSibling.InnerText
                });
            }
        }
        return listofitems;
    }
```

My XML looks as below:-

```
'<'PublisherProperty'>''<br/>
'<'Name'>'Channel'<'/Name'>'<br/>
'<'Value'>'943'<'/Value'>'<br/>
'<'PublisherID'>'PUBLISHER'<'/PublisherID'>'<br/>
'<'/PublisherProperty'>'<br/>
'<'PublisherProperty'>'<br/>
'<'Name'>'Queue'<'/Name'>'<br/>
'<'Value'>'q123'<'/Value'>'<br/>
'<'PublisherID'>'PUBLISHER'<'/PublisherID'>'<br/>
'<'/PublisherProperty'>'<br/>
'<'PublisherProperty'>'<br/>
'<'Name'>'QueueServer'<'/Name'>'<br/>
'<'Value'>'U4VMMQSIT02'<'/Value'>'<br/>
'<'PublisherID'>'PUBLISHER'<'/PublisherID'>'<br/>
'<'/PublisherProperty'>'<br/>
'<'PublisherProperty'>'<br/>
'<'Name'>'QueueName'<'/Name'>'<br/>
'<'Value'>'SIT</Value'>'<br/>
'<'PublisherID'>'PUBLISHER'<'/PublisherID'>'<br/>
'<'/PublisherProperty'>'<br/>
'<'PublisherProperty'>'<br/>
'<'Name'>'QueuePort'<'/Name'>'<br/>
'<'Value'>'2454'<'/Value'>'<br/>
'<'PublisherID'>'PUBLISHER'<'/PublisherID'>'<br/>
'<'/PublisherProperty'>'<br/>
'<'PublisherProperty'>'<br/>
'<'Name'>'QueueWaitInterval'<'/Name'>'<br/>
'<'Value'>'-1'<'/Value'>'<br/>
'<'PublisherID'>'PUBLISHER'<'/PublisherID'>'<br/>
'<'/PublisherProperty'>'<br/>
'<'PublisherProperty'>'<br/>
'<'Name'>'Exception</Name'>'<br/>
'<'Value'>'9501</Value'>'<br/>
'<'PublisherID'>'PUBLISHER'<'/PublisherID'>'<br/>
'<'/PublisherProperty'>'<br/>
'<'PublisherProperty'>'<br/>
'<'Name'>'ExceptionText'<'/Name'>'<br/>
'<'Value'>' Error'<'/Value'>'<br/>
'<'PublisherID'>'PUBLISHER '<'/PublisherID'>'<br/>
'<'/PublisherProperty'>'<br/>
'<'PublisherProperty'>'<br/>
'<'Name'>'MsgElement'<'/Name'>'<br/>
'<'Value'>'null</Value'>'<br/>
'<'PublisherID'>'PUBLISHER'<'/PublisherID'>'<br/>
'<'/PublisherProperty'>'<br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a collection and see if it's in there.

```
if (new[] { "Channel", "QueueManager", "QueueServer" , "QueueName" }.Contains( node.FirstChild.InnerText)){ }
```